# Uncaught ReferenceError: ReservationCard is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am trying to use ‘connect’ to get value from template reducer

I am facing the error below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ReservationCard is not defined

Here is the whole code, in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmfzLs3z/2/).

Providing the snippet code below:

```
export default React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
       value: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
       profile: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
       SPORTSDetails: React.PropTypes.shape({
           error: React.PropTypes.object,
           SPORTSId: React.PropTypes.number,
           SPORTSName: React.PropTypes.string,
           SPORTSAmount: React.PropTypes.number,
           SPORTSDate: React.PropTypes.string,
           isRetrieving: React.PropTypes.boolean
       }),
       onEdit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
   },

   displayName: 'ReservationCard',
})

export default connect(state => ({
    profile: state.template.profile,
}), null, null, {
    withRef: true // allows parent to access component functions
})(ReservationCard);
```

Comment: Uhm, it's clearly not defined, the only place you use the **variable** name `ReservationCard` is when you pass in at the bottom ?

Comment: @adeneo hey I have used it here also ---------> displayName: 'ReservationCard',             updated the code too

Comment: Uhm, that's just a string, `"ReservationCard" !== ReservationCard` ?

Answer (score 1):

Export default works only with one property. ( you can export one main value from a file. Everything else has to be named)

You must have your component defined and then used.
The way you do it now `displayName` is not associated with a component yet. The exported `React.createClass` is.

So you can define it in one place and use it with the connect function

```
let ReservationCard =  React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
         value: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
         profile: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
         SPORTSDetails: React.PropTypes.shape({
             error: React.PropTypes.object,
             SPORTSId: React.PropTypes.number,
             SPORTSName: React.PropTypes.string,
             SPORTSAmount: React.PropTypes.number,
             SPORTSDate: React.PropTypes.string,
             isRetrieving: React.PropTypes.boolean
         }),
         onEdit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
     },

     displayName: 'ReservationCard',
  })

  export default connect(state => ({
      profile: state.template.profile,

  }), null, null, {
      withRef: true // allows parent to access component functions
  })(ReservationCard);
```

Comment: i changed it but I am getting four more errors....any idea how to fix it -------> RestServiceAuthenticator.js:119 Error occurred in RestServiceAuthenticator.setupAuth   No valid cookies for auth proof service. second error ----------> index.js:40 Uncaught (in promise) undefined third erro---------> wcm-util.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0(…)

Comment: @texirv can you try reproducing your setup on http://www.webpackbin.com/ ?

Comment: @eltonkamamai now I am getting only this error------->Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined  -------> some problem with state.... this app is so big so its difficult to reproduce in webpackbin.com